# Use makefile to read and write files of multi-threaded executable programs, why the files record the same data

Tags: c, makefile

I'm running an executable program on a computer with 64 virtual cpus, and I want the program to use all of the virtual cpus. So I put the compiled executables in different folders and use makefiles to run them quickly. Therefore I wrote the following makefile(The executable program is ./bin/main):

```
LIST = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64

run:
    cd bin;\
    for i in $(LIST); do \
        mkdir $$i;\
        cp main $$i;\
        cd $$i;\
        nohup ./main &\
        cd ..;\
    done
```

This executable program will execute a loop 100,000 times, each loop has a series of file read and write copy operations(The upc_i of each cycle will be re-randomized), like:

```
  FILE *fp_2;
  fp_2 = fopen("iter_data.txt", "a");
  fprintf(fp_2, "%u ", upc_i);
  fclose(fp_2);
```

Copy iter_data.txt to iter_data_all.txt file when certain conditions are met, Then delete the iter_data.txt file

```
    int ch;
    FILE *sfp;
    FILE *dfp;
    char sname[FILENAME_MAX] = "iter_data.txt";
    char dname[FILENAME_MAX] = "iter_data_all.txt";
    
    if((sfp = fopen(sname, "r")) == NULL){
      printf("\aerror\n");
    } else {
      if ((dfp = fopen(dname, "a")) == NULL){
        printf("\aerror\n");
      }else {
        while ((ch = fgetc(sfp)) != EOF){
          fputc(ch, dfp);
        }
        fclose(dfp);
      }
      fclose(sfp);
    }

    if(remove("iter_data.txt") == 0)
    {
    }
```

When I ran the Makefile, it was indeed divided into 64 processes and used 64 virtual cpus, but the iter_data_all.txt in the 64 folders turned out to be the same content.

I don't understand why, is it because of the makefile? This doesn't seem to happen if I manually go into each folder and use the nohup ./main & command

I ran the above makefile but the iter_data_all.txt under 64 folders is the same.And I found that the number of data recorded in the iter_data_all.txt file is much less than the theoretical number of data. Seems like an overwrite happened?

I want the main program in each folder to run independently of each other, iter_data_all.txt should have different content along with the change of upc_i.

Randomize the process of getting seeds:

```
  for(uint32_t i = 0; i < NUM_OF_SEEDS; ++i)
  {
    for(uint32_t j = 0; j < sizeof(seed_t); ++j)
    {
      seeds->seed[i].raw[j] = rand();
    }
  }
  for(uint32_t i = 0; i < NUM_OF_SEEDS; ++i)
  {
    print("s: ", (uint64_t *)&seeds->seed[i], SIZEOF_BITS(seed_t));
  }
```

Comment: What it `upc_i`? Why do you expect it should differ in different processes?

Comment: `upc_i` is a random number generated each time the loop. Since it is a random number, it should be different in different processes. But I found that there are the same numbers in `iter_data_all.txt` in different folders.

Comment: How do you generate this random number? How do you initialize seed?

Comment: A seed will be randomized in each cycle, and I can be sure that `upc_i` should be a different value in each cycle, because if I manually run `cd bin` and `nohup ./main &`, it can be in different processes save different values

Comment: Show how do you initialize seed.

Comment: I used `rand()` from `stdlib.h`

Comment: Do you call `srand()` before using `rand()`? With what argument?

Comment: I didn't use `srand()` because I need to generate a binary random vector, I only get in `0 - RAND_MAX`, `RAND_MAX` is defined as `2147483647`.

Comment: You must call `srand()` with different seed to get different pseudo-random sequences.

Comment: I observed that the number of satisfied conditions in `iter_data_all.txt` is less than the theoretical number, so I am thinking whether it is multi-process that caused the problem of file coverage

Comment: Oh! I used `srand()` in the main function, I forgot about it: `srand(time(NULL));`

Comment: `time(NULL)` return seconds since Epoch, which is likely the same for invocations started at about the same time.

Comment: Yep, that is. Try to add more entropy, e.g. from process id: `srand(time(NULL)+getpid())`

Comment: You are correct, it does cause `problems`, but I am still puzzled by the fact that there is less data in `iter_data_all.txt` than the theoretical value, I always think that the `make` command may be a little different than if I run it manually directly.@Andreas